# We need to change the UPN in Azure. What do we need to do in / with Snowflake to be able to continue logging in please?

Tags: azure, authentication, upn

I have created a new Azure tenant, but Snowflake has been built align to the original tenant.  I have changed the Azure UPN for a test user, and despite re-provisioning Snowflake, the test user cannot login.  Is there a simple fix for this please? (I am not a BI developer, but a PM tasked with deploying a new tenant and starting to move platforms over to it.)

thanks!

Comment: if you could specify any steps that you have done. if I were you, I would start at the standard doc available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/howto-troubleshoot-upn-changes

Comment: thank you - i'll take a look at the doc.  i have simply gone into Azure AD, User, Edit a test user, modify the UPN and Save.  Then the test account was used to access snowflake.  the BI team di reprovision  but it had no impact unfortunately.  thanks for your reply!

Comment: looks like you have been dumped into a project. try the docs, do some steps and you will have more specific questions and the community will come to your rescue.

Comment: We've got a solution thanks now.  the guys have manually changed the names in snowflake to match Azure AD and all is now working!  thanks very much for your assistance.